# How to keep focus after validation when use tab key

Tags: javascript, jsp, tabs, cursor

I have input text fields in jsp, and I use onChange="validation(this);" to check if null input and so on, but when I use tab key, cursor will be move to next field, how can keep cursor on validation field?

```
function validation(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();

    if(value == "") {
        obj.focus();
        obj.select();
    }
 }
```

Comment: your onchange calls `validation(this)` - but validation expects an id! ... either `onChange="validation(this.id);"` or `function validation(obj) {` (and remove the `var obj = getElementById` line) - see if that helps

Comment: a quick look in the browser developer tools would show an error

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `validation` with button instead `onchange` event in input box .And `if(value == "")` value is a undefined so change the if condition with `!Obj.value.trim()` its catch the false condition .[`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM1r2m-qXUAhUHK48KHQgCD2AQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_trim_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNEDh_x7JMeCVu0sakhKLDvxAVHYaw&sig2=rTTsbDAXZiivZEEYOv6UNQ) used for remove unwanted space

**Updated**

use with `blur` 
event instead of `onchange` .Its only allow to next input only present input was filled.

```js
function validation(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();

    if(!obj.value.trim()) {
        obj.focus();
        //obj.select();
    }
 }
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" onblur="validation(this,event)">
<input id="input" type="text" onblur="validation(this,event)">
```

Comment: can I use input box?

Comment: In my form, there are also two buttons for save and back, when I click save, I hope onBlur action, but when I click back, I don't want to onBlur action, what can I do?

Comment: use `mousedown` instead of click for back button

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event on 'blur'. There after check for the keyCode. For tab key it is `0`. Using an setTimeout since the current element will loss focus as soon as the is a onblur event. Therefore providing a sufficient time gap before focusing back on the element

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('inputField');
obj.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 0 && event.target.value == '') {
    setTimeout(function(){
    event.target.focus();
  },1000)
    

  }
})
```

```html
<input id='inputField' onchange='validation(this.id)'>
```

Comment: @mikezang sorry I could not get you. This is working at my end. Can you please clarify what is not working?

Comment: check my comment above, in fact, there are two buttons save and back and some fields. I will check input length and null when I use tab key, and if I click save, validation also need to be done, but if I click back, no any validation, can you show me detail code?